# How to define my connection type for window 10?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, network-adapter

currently is using D link DWA-582 AC 1200 pcie adapter,but why my connection type still 802.11n? not suppose to be 802.11 ac?

and my router was AC1900 Wi-Fi Router

Answer (score 0):

The router may be set in compatibility mode (IE allow connections by 802.11b/g/n.) Which would make sense.

You should find a section of the routers admin panel that says what wireless mode to use for 2.4ghz and 5ghz, similar to this image:[image]

Set the frequency you connect to N/AC mode and  you should be fine. Consult your user manual or just look through the menus for where you change it!

Edit: I checked your manual, go to Advanced - Advanced Setup - Wireless Settings.
You should get the correct speed already if you connect to the 5ghz SSID, you will have to check what is is named as.

Comment: actually what i trying to ask is not about the router,the router come with 2 channel,2.4ghz and 5ghz..what i confuse is my PC wifi connection type still 802.11n,not suppose to be 802.11 ac?

SSID: 101pendita2
Protocol: 802.11n
Security type: WPA2-Personal
IPv4 address: 192.168.0.169
IPv4 DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Description: D-Link DWA-582 Wireless AC1200 Dual Band PCI Express Adapter
Driver version: 2023.4.720.2015
Physical address: ‎C4-12-F5-60-33-D5

Comment: Your computer and router negotiate what type they will use. The Router needs to advertise it can do 802.11ac (Which is what I show how to do) And then your computer needs to identify this and accept. Are  you connecting to the 2.4 or 5ghz ssid?

Comment: yes i already connect to 5ghz,but still running by 802.11n,i dont get it how to do the setup

Comment: Double check your router settings as I suggested and I'll have a quick look at how your pcie card works

Comment: Adapter should be fine, it takes its recommendation from the router. There should be a quality of service (QoS) option in your router, find that and search for something called WMM (Wi-Fi multimedia), if its disabled, enable it.

Comment: QOS i did set my pc is the highest,but i still get 802.11n

Comment: I'm honestly not sure in that case. There will be something on the router or adapter telling them to drop down to 802.11n. Both standards are compatible. Possibly range?

Comment: the router just door outside within 3 meters range,total range from pc to router in 5 meters range